# Max of a Date field into another field in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, select, max

I have a postgresql table wherein I have few fields such as id and date. I need to find the max date for that id and show the same into a new field for all the ids. SQLFiddle site was not responding so I have an example in the excel. Here is the screenshot of the data and the output for the table.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the windowing variant of `max`:

```
SELECT id, date, MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
FROM   mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might work:

```
WITH maxdts AS (
  SELECT id, max(dt) maxdt FROM table GROUP BY id
)
SELECT id, date, maxdt FROM table t, maxdts m WHERE t.id = m.id;
```

Keep in mind without more information that this could be a horribly inefficient query, but it will get you what you need.